# Custom color palette with BitmapPalette

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a custom palette in C#. My bitmap is as follows.

```
List<System.Windows.Media.Color> colors = new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>();

//Add List entries here

BitmapPalette bitmapPalette = new BitmapPalette(colors);
wb = new WriteableBitmap(Width, Height, dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Indexed8, bitmapPalette);
```

I need to create a map from 0-255. How do I get this done in the easiest way?

```
colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
```

One way of filling is as shown, but filling all 255 entries this way doesn't make sense. How do I fill using pixel values directly rather than `System.Windows.Media.Colors.[Color]`?

Comment: Is this what you want ?? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use the [Color.FromRgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Color.FromArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has a [`FromArgb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`FromRgb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method you can use, f.e.:

```
colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0));
```

For creating a grayscale map:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(i, i, i));
```